# Merging SQL Server 2000 databases into SQL Server 2008 databases

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anyone please let me know steps to merge databases from SQL Server 2000 to a database running on SQL Server 2008?

How the data of SQL Server 2000 system databases (master, tempdb, model, msdb) will be merged in system databases of SQL Server 2008

Comment: You typically **don't** merge any of the system databases - just your own

Comment: The system documentation will clearly tell you the steps to upgrade a database. If you have a any questions after you read this, then come back and ask.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a whole [white paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F2%2F0%2FB%2F20B90384-F3FE-4331-AA12-FD58E6AB66C2%2FSQL%2520Server%25202000%2520to%25202008%2520Upgrade%2520White%2520Paper.docx&rct=j&q=sql%20server%202000%20to%202008%20upgrade%20white%20paper&ei=q6pCTqLMEKvLsQK-9uXtCQ&usg=AFQjCNHREhaRPPZE_tjdjNENilWNKPNpIw&cad=rja) dedicated to the topic.

Comment: Marc, I agree but there are plenty of tables in the 2000 system databases...is there any tool to move them